# Getting Google Calendar event by id with Python and gdata library

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata

How could I get an event from a specific Google Calendar using gdata library and knowing the event id? I can't see an example like that in the documentation.

I know I can (and should) use v3 API and python-api-client, but I want to add and modify events in all the users's calendars from a Google Apps domain, without user's intervention. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance, and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-response:

```
from gdata.calendar.client import *
from gdata.calendar import *

gdclient = gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient(source = 'testing')

gdclient.ClientLogin(ADMIN_USER_LOGIN, ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD, gdclient.source)

feed_uri = gdclient.get_calendar_event_feed_uri(calendar = THE_USER_EMAIL)

event_uri = feed_uri + '/' + THE_EVENT_ID

calendar_entry = gdclient.get_calendar_entry(event_uri, desired_class=gdata.calendar.data.CalendarEventEntry))
```

One thing I've realized is there's no way to change the event's color (or, at least, I've not found it). This is possible with Google Calendar API v3.